# Forwarding traffic via ssh from printer to raspberry pi

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-tunneling, http-proxy

At my place of work, we have two different kinds of printers: Konica and HP. They are connected to our network and each have a specific ip. Each employee has an account they must access before printing. One way is using a fob; however, the Konica and HP encode differently - hex vs string.

With that said, to solve this matter my idea involves a man in the middle solution where I overwrite the outgoing response before being sent to another server. I have a proxy server loaded up on a raspberry pi.

I want to ssh into the printer from the raspberry pi and forward the outgoing traffic from the printer to some arbitrary port on my raspberry pi, so that my code can connect to that port. My proxy server and code are all taken care of but I do not know how to set up the ssh from the raspberry pi to the printer.

printer -> raspberry pi -> server

Comment: Most printers don't support ssh. Are you certain that these do?

Comment: I am perhaps ignorant on the matter, but I was under the assumption the printer ran on some version of linux to which I could ssh into. I am not certain, however.

Comment: It most likely is linux under the hood - but that doesn't mean it a) runs `sshd` and b) if it does lets you mess with it ... None of the printers I've come across so far were running `sshd`